# How can I diagnose and fix an intermittent disk connection issue?

Tags: debian, ssd, freeze, sata, smart

I have a Lenovo X250 notebook running Debian testing. It has a 512 GB Crucial MX100 2.5" SATA SSD.

Occasionally, the computer will lock up, and I'll need to restart. If I'm able to switch to a console, I see lots of messages about `ATA COM RESET` and btrfs read / write errors. Sometimes it will become responsive but with the root filesystem mounted read-only, and not actually readable. Files in the cache can be read, but not other files.

Weird things:

- it can go for many days without acting up
- it is *strongly* correlated with moving the computer while it's on; I've taken to always closing the lid when moving
- the issue requires cycling power to resolve -- a soft reboot via magic sysreq will end up with BIOS not finding a bootable device

My vague belief is that there's some kind of contact affected by flex of the chassis. Things I've tried:

- checking SMART status (all clear)
- reseating the drive

I do not have a spare 2.5" SATA SSD to test with. I can certainly get a new one, but would prefer not to unless I expect it to fix things.

*Any* ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Output of `smartctl -A`:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.14.0-2-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt 0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5888
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7741
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   0x0032   086   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       431
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       126
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       4403
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Error_Correction_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   074   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       26 (Min/Max 12/60)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Percent_Lifetime_Used   0x0031   086   086   000    Pre-fail  Offline      -       14
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
210 Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Total_Host_Sector_Write 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31996614953
247 Host_Program_Page_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1008715183
248 Bckgnd_Program_Page_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       258122736
```

Comment: You should highly consider posting the output of `smartctl -A /dev/sda`. There could be something others know to be an issue you aren't familiar with.

Comment: @DrewChapin thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention any of these things, so I'm going to list them:

1. Check the disk's SMART error logs. If you can show that there are errors and the drive is still covered under manufacturer warranty, Crucial will replace it.

   ```
   smartctl -l error /dev/sda
   ```
2. Run a conveyence test and move the laptop around while it's performing the test.

   ```
   smartctl -t conveyance /dev/sda
   ```

   From the manpage:

   > conveyance - [ATA only] runs a SMART Conveyance Self Test (minutes). This self-test routine is intended to identify damage incurred during transporting of the device. This self-test routine should take on the order of minutes to complete. Note that this command can be given during normal system operation (unless run in captive mode - see the '-C' option below).
3. Run `long` self-test.

   ```
   smartctl -t long /dev/sda
   ```

   > long - [ATA] runs SMART Extended Self Test (tens of minutes to several hours). This is a longer and more thorough version of the Short Self Test described above. Note that this command can be given during normal system operation (unless run in captive mode - see the '-C' option below).
4. If it was manufactured before March 2015, there is a firmware update for the drive. This could help. The last note in the release summary about correcting reporting for SMART attribute 5, which is reallocated sector count (technically, failed flash memory blocks since this is an SSD), is particularly suspect to me. You could have a high number of reallocated sectors and SMART not be reporting it correctly.

   > Release Date: 03/10/2015
   >
   > Firmware for the MX100 (all form factors) is being updated from version MU01 to MU02. The MX100 is updateable to this new firmware starting from previous versions using tools provided by Micron.
   >
   > This update will be mandatory cut-in for new product built in Micron factories, and is an OPTIONAL update for any drive in the field. For end users, it is recommended if the user is experiencing or wishes to prevent an issue related to the following items.
   >
   > Version MU02 includes the following changes:
   >
   > Improved stability, Efficiency, and Performance during power state transitions
   >   Improved handling of environments with unstable power supplies
   >   Improved handling of environments with SATA interface signal integrity issues
   >   Improved response time for SMART read commands
   >   Corrected error handling NCQ Trim Commands
   >   Corrected reporting of SMART Attribute 5

   http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/support-ssd-firmware
5. Consider re-partitioning the drive, and possibly trying a different operating system. Particularly since you're using the *testing* flavor of Debian.
6. Consider that your issue is not the drive, and perhaps with the motherboard.
7. Remove the drive, and boot from a Debian live environment (flash drive, or CD). Try to replicate the freezing. Obviously, if it still does it, then it cannot be the drive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm working through these. I've run smart self-tests in the past, and seen no failures. The most recent was about 4 months ago according to the logs. The issue was already there then.